# Cloudfront differentiate origin based on hostname of the request

Tags: amazon-web-services, routes, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront, hostname

I have a Cloudfront distribution that I want to use it to serve two different hostnames (let's say 1.hostname.com and 2.hostname.com). In my CloudFormation template, I include these as aliases like below.

```
AppDistribution:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
    Properties:
        DistributionConfig:
            Origins:
                - DomainName: !Ref ALBDomainName1
                  Id: ALBOrigin1
                  CustomOriginConfig:
                      OriginProtocolPolicy: https-only
                      OriginSSLProtocols:
                          - TLSv1.2
                - DomainName: !Ref ALBDomainName2
                  Id: ALBOrigin2
                  CustomOriginConfig:
                      OriginProtocolPolicy: https-only
                      OriginSSLProtocols:
                          - TLSv1.2
            Aliases:
                - "1.hostname.com"
                - "2.hostname.com"                
            DefaultCacheBehavior:
                AllowedMethods:
                    - GET
                    - HEAD
                    - OPTIONS
                    - PUT
                    - PATCH
                    - POST
                    - DELETE
                TargetOriginId: ALBOrigin1
                ForwardedValues:
                    QueryString: False
                    Cookies:
                        Forward: none
                ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https
                MinTTL: 0
                DefaultTTL: 60
                MaxTTL: 60
                ResponseHeadersPolicyId: "123123"
```

I want to configure the cloudformation to use one origin if the request is coming to 1.hostname.com and the other origin if the request is coming to 2.hostname.com. The path pattern can be the same in both cases. Is there a way to add `CacheBehaviors` achieve this?